# MySQL --secure-file-priv option error even if I change the secure_file_priv

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064

I use the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax in MySQL and the system report that I have a --secure-file-priv option error. Then I searched for that porblem and change the path to my frequently-used path and then reboot MySQL, but the problem still exist as follows:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'secure%'
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                                         |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| secure_auth      | ON                                            |
| secure_file_priv | E:\career\QuantumFinancialService\data_extra\ |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\career\QuantumFinancialService\data_extra\test.csv' INTO TABLE test1;
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

How can I fixed this?

BTW if I put my secure_file_priv as this, does that works for my subfolders too? say 'E:\career\QuantumFinancialService\data_extra\foo\'.

And is there a way to shut this whole secure thing down?

PS: This is definitely not a duplicate problem! please look carefully!

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I read that and I already changed the secure_file_priv in my.ini, can't you see that?! Why you marked my question as duplicator?!

Comment: I doubt that your problem cannot be solved by using the duplicate link.

Comment: @DirkPaul I am getting same issue after setting up secure_file_priv value , do you have any idea how did you fixed this?